User deleted Google Service Account files; Service Account has not reclaimed storage space
The files owned by a Google Service Account were trashed and permanently deleted from the trash by my normal user account; Service Account storage space was not reclaimed as expected. Existing files owned by the Service Account adds up to 4.56 GB (4557015060 bytes), the about Google Drive API response says the Service Account usage is 16.08 GB (16084076368 bytes). The difference is 11.52 GB -- what I should have gotten back.
I tried using the API to get a list of deleted files but they do not show up at all for either the normal user nor for the Google Service Account. I tried uploading then deleting a tiny file using the Google Service Account in the hopes that it could recalculate the storage space but that had little effect. The files were permanently deleted over 2 weeks ago. What am I missing?
The below is node.js code that I'm using to get the existing files for the Service Account.
let params = {
  'q': '"' + api.google.folder_id + '" in parents AND trashed=false',
  'pageSize': 1000,
  'fields': 'files(id,size,name,ownedByMe,createdTime,trashed,explicitlyTrashed,properties)',
  'supportsAllDrives': 'true',
  'includeItemsFromAllDrives': 'true'
};
var query_string = factory.getQueryUrl(params);
let request = {
  // 'url': 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q="' + api.google.folder_id + '"+in+parents+AND+trashed=false&fields=files(originalFilename,+properties)&supportsAllDrives=true&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true',
  'url': 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?' + query_string,
  'method': 'GET',
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api.google.access_token
  }
};


service accounts are not You they have their own google drive account, any files stored on the service accounts drive account will be gone when its deleted.   If you had it upload files on your personal drive account and granted yourself access to them you should have access to delete them. the service accounts access should have been removed when it was deleted.  There is nothing in the About response for a standard account that mentions service account.

would you mind adding some code here so that who ever it is that closed voted your question as not programming related can see that service accounts are used with google drive api to access google drive server to server.

I understand Service Accounts are separate from my own personal google drive account and have their own quota. The About API request was done using the Service Account which is where it tells me it's used 16.08GB. Yet trying to upload a 100MB file using the Service Account results in a The user's Drive storage quota has been exceeded error. Not sure what else to try.

Upload a smaller file or have it upload to your personal drive account

I tried that too. I uploaded a text file that was only a few bytes long. That worked and then I deleted it using the service account. The used quota changed very slightly but that was all that happened.
